# Carrierwave Remote URL error raise IOError, 'attempt to read body out of block' if @socket.closed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I upload an image remotely using remote_url from CarrierWave on my Rails application. It used to work fine but now I get an issue

**Controller**

```
@pool = Pool.new(remote_main_picture_url: "https://myimageurl...")
if @pool.save //is causing the error
....
end
```

**Uploader**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "#{ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME']}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png svg webp)
  end

  process resize_to_fit: [2000, 2000]

  version :medium do
    process resize_to_fit: [400, 400]
  end

  def filename
    @name ||= "#{mounted_as}_#{timestamp}.png" if original_filename.present?
  end

  def timestamp
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma'

gem 'bootsnap', '1.10.3', require: false
gem "webpacker"

gem 'carrierwave', '~> 2.0'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'mini_magick'
```

**Error message**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
raise IOError, 'attempt to read body out of block' if @socket.closed?
```

The error seems to be linked to net/http, I don't know what has changed to cause this issue... Maybe a gemfile update...

Comment: I have the same error using ruby 2.7.6 on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Carrierwave install gem ssrf_filter like dependency and lasted version of this gem prodused this problem.
You need install ssrf_filter gem of version '1.0.8'

`gem 'ssrf_filter', '1.0.8'`

More details on https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2625